# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]' ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, image

Hi i was just making a web application in asp.net to perform CRUD operations which include image file operations too. This web application consume a web service to perform the database operations.

When running on IIS i am stuck at following error.

" Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]' "

Could you please help?. The same application code was working without any issues when the web service wasn't used.

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArhOS.jpg)

Code for image view in FilmGrid.aspx.cs file

```
 FilmService.FilmCrud objFCRUD = new FilmService.FilmCrud();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Refreshdata();
            }
        }

        //To display entire film database as gridview
        protected void Refreshdata()
        {
            DataSet dTbl = new DataSet();
            XmlElement exelement = objFCRUD.SelectRecord(0);
            if (exelement != null)
            {
                XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(exelement);
                dTbl.ReadXml(nodeReader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
                gvMovies.DataSource = dTbl;
                gvMovies.DataBind();
            }
        }
 

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                    string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["poster"]);                          
                    (e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl;
                }
            }
```

My FilmGrid.aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMovies" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="4" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="217px" Width="1491px">                       
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="film_id" HeaderText ="Film Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="film_name" HeaderText ="Film Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="actor" HeaderText ="Actor" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="actress" HeaderText ="Actress" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pub_date" HeaderText ="Published Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="director" HeaderText ="Director" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="producer" HeaderText ="Producer" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="prod_cost" HeaderText ="Production Cost" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dist_cost" HeaderText ="Distribution Cost" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText ="Category" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cert_category" HeaderText ="Certified Category" />                              
                <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:Image ID="Image1" HeaderText ="Poster" runat="server" Width="122px" Height="148px"/></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/AddFilm.aspx?film_id="+Eval("film_id") %>'/></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `dr["poster"]`? What is the data type of that column? Could it be a base64 encoded value?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing poster field is VARBINARY(MAX) in database. Image is saved as binary data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `dr["poster"]` returns a string and you can't directly cast (which here means using `(your_type_here)`) convert a string to a byte[]. Look at Piotr Szuflicki's solution for how to properly convert a string to a byte[].

Comment: @user16515314 Then again are you sure you want to convert from string to byte[] to string?

Comment: string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + (dr["poster"]); worked perfect!!! My Bad

Comment: and for bonus points you can remove the unnecessary parantheses (which are the `(` and `)` around `dr["poster"]`). Good luck on your coding journey!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly cast string to byte[].

You have to use, for example Encoding class.

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Your string");
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-string-to-byte-array/

Or you can try taking char array from the string and then cast each char to byte.